# Apache Spark Batch Processing Job Optimization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections, rdd

I am new to Scala and Spark, am facing some issues writing a migration code from MR job to Spark. Basically I need help to refactor/optimize the code I have written till now and also the identify an approach to complete my task further.

**My questions are as below :**

1. Can the statement `if (!usefulData.isEmpty())` for RDD empty check be implemented in some other way, like inside a filter function. The map or reduction/aggregation functions should be called only if the output of filter returns some rows (Basically using scala Option class somehow)
2. If you see the code, to generate each KPI, I have to perform map operation again and again on `usefulData` which is the filtered and Parsed file data RDD. Is this a good approach, can we club some map operations in one?
3. Should I take the Spitted fields from input file into a Tuple having 16 indexes, or is there any other better/efficient way ?
4. If you see the KPI, `success_cnt, success_uu, failure_cnt and failure_uu`, they have almost the same processing, I want to create a common method for them. But unable to do so, I am not able to pass the tuple index as input to map inside the function
5. **Last but most important, I want a final approach to club all these KPIs, like we do in a HashMap in MR and write it to the context there (Basically facing problem, because in MR the map and reduce function work on single line from InputSplit, but here the whole file is processed at once using the transformations, so I can't create class level variables and write to a POJO class and then aggregate in Context)**

   My code is as below :

---

```
    import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
    import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
    import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
    import org.apache.spark.rdd._
    
    /**
      * Sample Data : 1 Line
      * 11685147    com.my.record.xxxxxx    2015-12-27      200 RECOVER <MacBookAir4,2> <Mac OS X;10.11.2;22222> <com.my.site>      0   com.my.os   1451248910234   1   10
      *
      * Parsed Data :
      * 
      * l._1 : 1685147
      * l._2 : com.my.record.xxxxxx
      * l._3 : 2015-12-27
      * l._4 :
      * l._5 : 200
      * l._6 : RECOVER
      * l._7 : MacBookAir4
      * l._8 : 22222
      * l._9 : Mac OS X
      * l._10 : 10.11.2
      * l._11 :
      * l._12 : 0/-6015
      * l._13 : com.my.os
      * l._14 : 1451248910234
      * l._15 : 1
      * l._16 : 10
      *
      **/
    
    object MySparkApp {
    
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
    
        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
        Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    
        val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My-Spark-App").set("spark.executor.memory", "2G").set("spark.driver.memory", "1G")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    
        val pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+".r
    
        def parseClientInfo(field: String) = {
          val fields = field.split(">")
    
          val devType = fields(0).trim.split(",")(0).substring(1).trim
          val devVersion = fields(1).trim.split(";")(2).trim
    
          val osType = fields(1).trim.split(";")(0).substring(1).trim
          val osVersion = fields(1).trim.split(";")(1).trim
    
          (devType, devVersion, osType, osVersion)
        }
    
        def parseFile = {
          val fileData = sc.textFile("file:///path_to_my_file")
          val filteredData = fileData.map(_.split("\\t")).filter(l => l(5).toLowerCase.matches("recover"))
          filteredData.map(l =>
            flattenTuple(l(0), l(1), l(2), l(3), l(4), l(5), parseClientInfo(l(6)), l(7), l(8), l(9), l(10), l(11), l(12)))
        }
    
        val usefulData = parseFile
        //usefulData.take(1).foreach(println)
        usefulData.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
    
    
        if (!usefulData.isEmpty()) {
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.CNT
            * AGG_CNT : _._16
            */
          val recover_count = usefulData.map(_._16.toDouble).sum.toInt
          println("recover_count : " + recover_count)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.UniqueUser
            * PRS_ID : _._1
            */
          val recover_uu = usefulData.map(l => l._1).distinct.count
          println("recover_uu : " + recover_uu)
    
          val (success, failure) = usefulData.map(l => ((l._1, l._5), l._16)).partitionRDDBy(_._1._2 == "200")
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.SUCCESS.COUNT
            * AGG_CNTs of SUCCESS : _._2
            */
          val success_cnt = success.map(l => l._2.toDouble).sum.toInt
          println("success_cnt : " + success_cnt)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.SUCCESS.UniqueUser
            * PRS_IDs of SUCCESS : _._1._1
            */
          val success_uu = success.map(l => l._1._1).distinct.count.toInt
          println("success_uu : " + success_uu)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.FAILURE.COUNT
            * AGG_CNTs of FAILURE : _._2
            */
          val failure_cnt = failure.map(l => l._2.toDouble).sum.toInt
          println("failure_cnt : " + failure_cnt)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.FAILURE.UniqueUser
            * PRS_IDs of FAILURE : _._1._1
            */
          val failure_uu = failure.map(l => l._1._1).distinct.count.toInt
          println("failure_uu : " + failure_uu)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.FAILSUCCESS.UniqueUser
            * PRS_IDs of SUCCESS and FAILURE : _._1
            */
          val fail_success_uu = success.map(l => l._1).join(failure.map(l => l._1)).count
          println(fail_success_uu)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.PCFAILURE.COUNT
            * RESPONSEs : l._5
            * ERROR_CODEs : l._12
            */
          val pc_failure_cnt = usefulData.filter(l => l._5 != "200" && l._12 == "-6015").map(l => l._16.toDouble).sum.toInt
          println("pc_failure_cnt : " + pc_failure_cnt)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.PCFAILURE.UniqueUser
            * RESPONSEs : l._5
            * ERROR_CODEs : l._12
            */
          val pc_failure_uu = usefulData.filter(l => l._5 != "200" && l._12 == "-6015").map(l => l._1).distinct.count.toInt
          println("pc_failure_uu : " + pc_failure_uu)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.RECORD.COUNT
            * LABELs : l._2
            * PRS_IDs : _._16
            */
          val record_cnt = usefulData.filter(l => l._2.contains("record")).map(l => l._16.toDouble).sum.toInt
          println("record_cnt : " + record_cnt)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.RECORD.SUCCESS.UniqueUser
            * RESPONSEs : l._5
            * LABELs : l._2
            * PRS_IDs : _._1
            */
          val record_success_uu = usefulData.filter(l => l._5 == "200" && l._2.contains("record")).map(l => l._1).distinct.count.toInt
          println("record_success_uu : " + record_success_uu)
    
          /**
            * KPI : RECOVER.RECORD.FAILURE.UniqueUser
            * RESPONSEs : l._5
            * LABELs : l._2
            * PRS_IDs : _._1
            */
          val record_failure_uu = usefulData.filter(l => l._5 != "200" && l._2.contains("record")).map(l => l._1).distinct.count.toInt
          println("record_failure_uu : " + record_failure_uu)
    
          /**
            * Group KPI 1 - DVC.VER.UniqueUser
            * DEVICE_TYPEs : l._7
            * PRS_IDs : l._1
            */
          val group_ver_uu = usefulData.map(l => (l._7, l._1)).distinct.aggregateByKey(0)((acc, value) => acc + 1, _ + _)
          println("group_ver_uu : ")
          group_ver_uu.collect().foreach(println)
    
          if (!group_ver_uu.isEmpty) {
    
            /**
              * Group KPI 2 - DVC.UniqueUser
              * DEVICE_TYPE WITHOUT VERSION : l._1
              * COUNT OF SIMILAR DEVICES IRRESPECTIVE OF VERSIONs : l._2
              */
            val group_uu = group_ver_uu.map(l => ((pattern findFirstIn l._1).getOrElse(None), l._2)).aggregateByKey(0)((acc, value) => acc + value, _ + _)
            println("group_uu")
            group_uu.collect.foreach(println)
    
            val (macData, otherDevices) = group_uu.partitionRDDBy(l => l._1.toString.toLowerCase.contains("mac"))
    
            /**
              * KPI : RECOVER.DVC.MAC.UniqueUser
              */
            val mac_uu = macData.aggregate(0)((acc, value) => acc + value._2, _ + _)
            println("mac_uu : " + mac_uu)
    
          }
    
          /**
            * Group KPI 3 - OS.UniqueUser
            * OS_TYPEs : l._9
            * PRS_IDs : l._1
            */
          val group_os_uu = usefulData.map(l => (l._9, l._1)).distinct.aggregateByKey(0)((acc, value) => acc + 1, _ + _)
          println("group_os_uu")
          group_os_uu.collect().foreach(println)
    
          /**
            * Group KPI 2 - OS.VER.UniqueUser
            * OS_TYPEs : l._9
            * OS_VERSIONS : l._10
            * PRS_IDS : l._1
            */
          val group_os_ver_uu = usefulData.map(l => ((l._9, l._10), l._1)).distinct.aggregateByKey(0)((acc, value) => acc + 1, _ + _)
          println("group_os_ver_uu")
          group_os_ver_uu.collect().foreach(println)
        }
      }
    
      implicit class RDDOps[T](rdd: RDD[T]) {
        def partitionRDDBy(f: T => Boolean): (RDD[T], RDD[T]) = {
          val passes = rdd.filter(f)
          val fails = rdd.filter(e => !f(e))
          (passes, fails)
        }
      }
    
      implicit def flattenTuple[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P](t: (A, B, C, D, E, F, (G, H, I, J), K, L, M, N, O, P)): (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P) = {
        (t._1, t._2, t._3, t._4, t._5, t._6, t._7._1, t._7._2, t._7._3, t._7._4, t._8, t._9, t._10, t._11, t._12, t._13)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the questions precisely, but here is an attemp:

1. You can use predicate : `usefulData.count==0`. One more solution is :

   `rdd.mapPartitions(iter => Iterator(! iter.hasNext)).reduce(_&&_)`
2. It totally depends on the logic. Basically for each KPI you are creating a new branch in the DAG. In case you see overlapping logic, you can definitely save the common tranformations to happen multiple times.
3. Not sure about this, I too use Tuple for upto 9-10 fields. Though the max size is 22.
4. I had a similar issue few days back. So now high time to ask this question: [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091354/scala-get-nth-element-from-tuple)
5. Offcourse you can. Your strategy should involve 1) creating a new List/Array of indices of your records. 2) Perform transformations on your RDD, preferably using mapPartions. The results of each KPI should have same cardinality as of input RDD (use Options to avoid failures). 3. Use
   `zip/zipWithIndex` the KPI RDDs. I guess this is what you are looking for.

Please update/answer this thread if you find remaining answers.

Comment: 1. The predicate which you mentioned works fine.  Actually I didn't check earlier, if I use this condition in a filter function and then perform a map afterwards, will it throw a exception if no elements are found after the filter. Now I have checked after changing the code and the aggregation also returns `0 ` if there are no filtered rows (and not an exception, as I feared). But considering we are using `usefulData` in all the RDDs, I think it would be better to do the check once in `if` condition like I have done, instead of every RDD filter.

Comment: Well Basically what I meant here is, lets consider these 2 RDDs    :    `val success_cnt = success.map(l => l._2.toDouble).sum.toInt`   and   `val success_uu = success.map(l => l._1._1).distinct.count.toInt`

Comment: Can I do something like this : (Might look very Stupid, but you never know there are many ways in scala    :    `success.mapPartition{ val index2Sum = ??? (perform the aggreagation here) val index1count = ??? (perform the aggreagation here) } yield index2Sum`