# Scala: Get sum of nth element from tuple array/RDD

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I have a array of `tuple` like this:

```
val a = Array((1,2,3), (2,3,4))
```

I want to write a generic method for a method like below:

```
def sum2nd(aa: Array[(Int, Int, Int)]) = {
      aa.map { a => a._2 }.sum
      }
```

So what I am looking for a method like:

```
def sumNth(aa: Array[(Int, Int, Int)], n: Int)
```

Comment: Are the tuple elements always the same type?

Comment: lets assume for simplicity, same type and tuple of same size

Comment: If you want an indexed sequence (which is what you seem to want), use a datastructure that is an IndexedSequence! (e.g. List, Array, Vector).  If you want to access element `n` for variable `n`, then Tuples are the wrong choice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about this. The simplest is to use `productElement`:

```
def unsafeSumNth[P <: Product](xs: Seq[P], n: Int): Int =
  xs.map(_.productElement(n).asInstanceOf[Int]).sum
```

And then (note that indexing starts at zero, so `n = 1` gives us the second element):

```
scala> val a = Array((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4))
a: Array[(Int, Int, Int)] = Array((1,2,3), (2,3,4))

scala> unsafeSumNth(a, 1)
res0: Int = 5
```

This implementation can crash at runtime in two different ways, though:

```
scala> unsafeSumNth(List((1, 2), (2, 3)), 3)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
  at ...

scala> unsafeSumNth(List((1, "a"), (2, "b")), 1)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
  at ...
```

I.e., if the tuple doesn't have enough elements, or if the element you're asking for isn't an `Int`.

You can write a version that doesn't crash at runtime:

```
import scala.util.Try

def saferSumNth[P <: Product](xs: Seq[P], n: Int): Try[Int] = Try(
  xs.map(_.productElement(n).asInstanceOf[Int]).sum
)
```

And then:

```
scala> saferSumNth(a, 1)
res4: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(5)

scala> saferSumNth(List((1, 2), (2, 3)), 3)
res5: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 3)

scala> saferSumNth(List((1, "a"), (2, "b")), 1)
res6: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.ClassCastException: ...
```

This is an improvement, since it forces callers to address the possibility of failure, but it's also kind of annoying, since it forces callers to address the possibility of failure.

If you're willing to use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) you can have the best of both worlds:

```
import shapeless._, shapeless.ops.tuple.At

def sumNth[P <: Product](xs: Seq[P], n: Nat)(implicit
  atN: At.Aux[P, n.N, Int]
): Int = xs.map(p => atN(p)).sum
```

And then:

```
scala> sumNth(a, 1)
res7: Int = 5
```

But the bad ones don't even compile:

```
scala> sumNth(List((1, 2), (2, 3)), 3)
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter atN: ...
```

This still isn't perfect, though, since it means the second argument has to be a literal number (since it needs to be known at compile time):

```
scala> val x = 1
x: Int = 1

scala> sumNth(a, x)
<console>:19: error: Expression x does not evaluate to a non-negative Int literal
       sumNth(a, x)
                 ^
```

In many cases that's not a problem, though.

To sum up: If you're willing to take responsibilty for reasonable code crashing your program, use `productElement`. If you want a little more safety (at the cost of some inconvenience), use `productElement` with `Try`. If you want compile-time safety (but some limitations), use Shapeless.

Answer (score 3):

Antoher typesafe way to do it without using `shapeless` is to provide a function to extract the element you need:

```
def sumNth[T, E: Numeric](array: Array[T])(extract: T => E) =
  array.map(extract).sum
```

Then you can define `sum2nd` like this:

```
def sum2nd(array: Array[(Int, Int, Int)]): Int = sumNth(array)(_._2)
```

Or like this:

```
val sum2nd: Array[(Int, Int, Int)] => Int = sumNth(_)(_._2)
```

Comment: This is a reasonable solution, if you ignore the fact that the OP is asking for a specific signature / usage. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, though it's not really type safe:

```
  def sumNth(aa: Array[Product], n: Int)= {
    aa.map { a =>
      a.productElement(n) match {
        case i:Int => i
        case _ => 0
      }
    }.sum
  }

sumNth(Array((1,2,3), (2,3,4)), 2) // 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Scala 3, elements of a tuple can be accessed by indexed with a function invocation-like syntax (e.g. `t(1)` to get the second element of a tuple `t`). The `sumNth` method can thus be implemented like so:

```
def sumNth(arr: Array[(Int, Int, Int)], n: Int) = arr.map(_(n).asInstanceOf[Int]).sum
```

[Scastie Demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/r6HFg93dRleo7AQq8bIKpA)

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer, which I have upvoted. I just want to note that although Scala 3 has added this, the comments above about tuples being the wrong choice here still apply (except perhaps in some highly unusual contexts). Tuples are not collections.